# awk record separator (command-line vrs run-time)

Tags: awk

I'm processing several files and really need to change the record separator between files.  There is a problem re-processing the first line after the RS variable changes even though I'm telling `awk` to reprocess the line after RS changes.

I need this to output just 1 (not 1~):

```
$ echo "1~"|awk '{RS="~"; $0=$0; print $1}'
1~
```

I see everyone recommend this be done on the command line or in the BEGIN block.  I can do neither, because this is the RS needed on the second file (not the first).

The real example is kind of lengthy, here it is incase it helps.  I'm first building a table from a pipe delimited file.  Next, I go into parsing an EDI message.  The EDI message uses > to delimit its fields and ~ at the end of each line.  To make this more fun, the EDI message also includes CR LF lines.

```
{ 
  if(FILENAME == "ndc_sub.txt") {
    if(FS!="|"){
      FS=OFS="|"
      RS=ORS="\r\n"
      $0=$0 #reparse
    }
    account=$1
    ndc=$2
    service_date=$3
    new_ndc=$4
    ndc_sub[account,service_date,ndc]=new_ndc
    #print account" "service_date" "ndc
    next
  } 
  if(FS=="|") {
    FS=OFS=">"
    RS=ORS="~\r\n"
    $0=$0 #reparse

    #17 is the last field, the problem is it prints the value (good) but includes the "~" too
    print $17

  }
}
/^EL1/ { ... }
```

Comment: Well, if all you want to do is remove the `~`, you can do `tr -d '~' <<< "1~"`. Other than that, I didn't get your question. May a small real example would help.

Comment: think of the tilda as a new line.. Except I have to set it at run time inside of a if block (if(FILENAME="file2"){RS="~"....

Comment: @jcalfee314 Still going to be clearer and easier to help if you come up with a small real example of an input/expected output.

Comment: You can specify variables between variable names like `awk '...' file1 RS="~" file2` which allows you to change field/record separators between files among other things.

Comment: I would preprocess the EDI file, removing the CR from the CRLF endings.  Can you have newlines embedded in a 'line' between `~` record separators?  Is the `~` in addition to the newline after it?  Whatever the scheme, I'd run an 'EDI transformer' on the file first, then run the `awk` on the first and second files.

Comment: @n0741337 has the right answer but I notice the same misconception a couple of times in your code so just want to fix that: `$0=$0` does not cause awk to re-read the current record. The record is already read and stored in `$0`. All `$0=$0` does is tell awk to re-split the record into fields so you cannot, for example, set `RS` to some character that's already present in `$0` (e.g. `~`) and hope that awk will somehow split the current record into multiple records around that character. Changing FS will have an effect, changing RS will not. I'd change `#reparse` to `#re-split $0` for clarity.